# Pgfplots: Calculating linear regression, but ignore outliners for certain Y values

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

So i have a scatter diagram and generated a regression line.
There are some outliner that heavily influence that line.
I would like them to be ignored for the calculation of the linear regression.
It should be done based on their Y values.

There is already a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247808/pgfplots-calculate-a-linear-regression-ignoring-some-data).
But the answer there is to skip the first few X values.
Unfortunately that is not what I need.

So that is my current code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[scatter/classes={a={mark=*,draw=black}}]
            \pgfplotstableread{
                a     b
                0   0.5
                1   48
                2   1.4
                3   37
                4   3.4
                5   6.8
                6   4.5
                7   3.9
                8   10
                9   13
            }\datatable
        
            \addplot[scatter, only marks, scatter src=explicit symbolic]
            table[
                x=a,
                y=b,
            ] {\datatable};
            
            \addplot[
                thick,
                %% y filter/.expression={y<35 ? y : nan},
            ]
            table [
                x = a,
                %% y expr = {(\thisrow{b} > 35 ? nan : \thisrow{b} )},
                y = {create col/linear regression={y=b}},
            ] {\datatable};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

That code generates into this:

[image]

I already tried the `y filter` and `y expr`, but that doesn't really work.

I also thought about split the outliner into a several file.
But as my real graph has 4 regression lines and I would end up having ~8 files.
That doesn't seem practical for me.

So my question:
How can I ignore Y values over 30 for the calculation of the linear regression?

Comment: Welcome to SE. Always provide a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) so that people can copy-paste it, test it and suggest modifications. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about begin/end document. I thought that is already an MWE, but your right. Thank you!

Comment: You could split the dataset: one contains regular data, which you do fit, the other one has the outliers, which you plot. You can do this manually inline or via external files.

Answer (score 1):

You do not wish to filter the output coordinates of your line. I do know if there is a better way, but one way is to set the variance of the unwanted points high(the default value is `1` and `1000` will mean that they are almost not used) like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[scatter/classes={a={mark=*,draw=black}}]
            \pgfplotstableread{
                a     b
                0   0.5
                1   48
                2   1.4
                3   37
                4   3.4
                5   6.8
                6   4.5
                7   3.9
                8   10
                9   13
            }\datatable
        
            \addplot[scatter, only marks, scatter src=explicit symbolic]
            table[
                x=a,
                y=b,
            ] {\datatable};
            
            \addplot[
                thick,
            ]
            table [
                x = a,
                y = {create col/linear regression={y=b, variance={create col/expr={\thisrow{b}<30?1:1000}}}},
            ] {\datatable};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with outliers and linear fit]

Comment: Scientifically, this looks highly dodgy/dubious.

Comment: @AubreyBlumsohn: No it does not. There can and will be objective reasons to consider specific data points outliers and not to include them in any analysis. Anyway this site is not about good/bad science - it is about LaTeX and friends.